# Adding text string to CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the following SQL CASE:

```
SELECT 
BomMast.BomStockCode
, BomMast.BomDescription
, CASE
           WHEN StkItem.AveUCst <= 0 THEN 'ERROR' 
           WHEN StkItem.AveUCst > 0 THEN (StkItem.AveUCst * BomComp.ProductionQty) 
        END AS TotalCost
FROM BomComp
INNER JOIN BomMast
ON BomMast.BomID = BomComp.BomMasterKey
INNER JOIN StkItem
ON StkItem.StockLink = BomComp.ComponentStockLink
```

But I get the following message:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

Am I not allowed to add test within the CASE statement?

Thank you!

Comment: Of course you are allowed, but it seems one of the columns within your CASE is a varchar. Is it the qty or unit cost? Either that or you haven't told us, but are then INSERTing from this SELECT, into a column that cannot handle the 'ERROR' value if it appears.

Comment: make sure THEN (StkItem.AveUCst * BomComp.ProductionQty)  both column should be float

Comment: You can convert varchar like this convert(varchar(25), (StkItem.AveUCst * BomComp.ProductionQty) )

Comment: A `CASE` *expression* is something that computes a scalar value of a specific *type*. But you're attempting to have it return two possible values of *different* types.

Comment: Hi @underscore_d . The 'ERROR' is what I want to display if the AveUCst (Average Unit Cost) is less than or equal to zero. That way I can see which unit costs need to be updated at a later stage.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but it's not a particularly good idea, because as noted, the only solution to this is to `cast` even the non-error cases to `varchar`, which dilutes the purpose of the source columns being`float` in the first place. Personally I would return a `null` (which doesn't conflict with the column type) and then prettify or otherwise deal with this in the application stage, not the query.

Comment: @underscore_d using NULL also works! Many thanks!

Comment: @underscore_d I agree with you, `NULL` is a much better option.

Comment: @GrayMeiring Cool, and it has the benefit that you could avoid the `cast` now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, text can be used as the result a case statement, as can any datatype, but each case must return the same type, as the results column must have **one type** only.

Your `[TotalCost]` column has conflicting data types. `[StkItem.AveUCst]` is a **float** and the literal value of `'ERROR'` is a **varchar**. If you are intending to retain the benefits of number-based value in your results column, consider replacing `'ERROR'` with the SQL keyword `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT BomMast.BomStockCode
    ,BomMast.BomDescription
    ,CASE 
        WHEN StkItem.AveUCst <= 0
            THEN 'ERROR'
        WHEN StkItem.AveUCst > 0
            THEN CAST((StkItem.AveUCst * BomComp.ProductionQty) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
        END AS TotalCost
FROM BomComp
INNER JOIN BomMast ON BomMast.BomID = BomComp.BomMasterKey
INNER JOIN StkItem ON StkItem.StockLink = BomComp.ComponentStockLink
```

The datatypes of the values you want to show in either branches of your `CASE` statements need to be the same in order to work.

**Edit:**

After **@underscore_d**'s suggestion, I also consider that it would be a far better option to display `NULL` instead of the message `ERROR` and then handle this `NULL` value in the application level.

Hence, your case statement will change to:

```
CASE 
    WHEN StkItem.AveUCst <= 0
        THEN NULL
    WHEN StkItem.AveUCst > 0
        THEN (StkItem.AveUCst * BomComp.ProductionQty)
END AS TotalCost
```

Comment: With the obvious caveat that if the receiving application/table/whatever needs that column to be a float (in non-error cases), this now can't happen.

Comment: @underscore_d Correct, that will have to be handled on the application/table level. We can speculate different solutions for all possibilities (table/application) but without the OP presenting the scope of this, I'm going to limit myself to correcting the query and explaining why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

Your column `TotalCost` (neither any other column) can be a type-mixture. In first case it would be a `varchar`, in second case it would be `float`or something like that. THAT IS NOT POSSIBLE.